# default keyword virtual destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been using more and more C++11 and I have come across something that I couldn't find anywhere. When we delete derived class from base pointer, we need to have virtual destructors;  but sometimes the parent destructor needs to be "pure", which is not really possible with C++. So, my question is can **default** be used for virtual destructors? I have already tried it and it works but I don't know if its safe as there is no information about it anywhere in the internet.

EDIT: To clarify the problem, I am talking about using `virtual ~Class() = default;`

Comment: `virtual ~Class() = 0;` has not been removed from the language.

Comment: `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Component::~Component()", referenced from: PhysicsComponent::~PhysicsComponent() in PhysicsComponent.o` - This happens when I use pure virtual

Comment: @Gasim You still need to specify an implementation for it, because it will always be called.

Comment: Then what is the point of using pure virtual destructor. Is it to force derived classes to have a destructor during compilation? If it is, thats not what I need. Is using `virtual ~Class()=default;` 'legal' C++?

Comment: @Gasim: Having a pure virtual destructor does the class abstract pure even if the class has no other virtual pure method. Btw, `= default` is legal C++11.

Comment: @Gasim: So your Q is just: is `virtual ~Class() = default;` legal ? if so, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is virtual ~Base() = default; legal

Yes. it is.

If you want to have a pure virtual destructor, you can do the following:

```
class Base
{
public;
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
```

and provide implementation:

```
Base::~Base() = default; // or any other implementation
```

So `Base` is virtual pure. It can be done with pre C++11 (change `= default;` by `{}`).

Comment: my goal is not to have a pure virtual destructor. I like using `=default` instead of `{}` mostly for naming.

Answer (score 3):

In this case it's simpler to just use `virtual ~Class() {}`. It has the same meaning, it's shorter, and you don't need to mess around with implementation. `= default` is mostly useful for copy/move constructors/assignment operators, rather than destructors.

Comment: It does _not_ have the same meaning. If there are no other pure virtual functions then the class will no longer be abstract.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it wouldn't be pure if you use either `{}` or `=default`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was reading it as `= 0`. Didn't see the edit I suppose. Then, yes, this is a good suggestion. :)